# Before Delete Trigger : Need to compare User with the Owner

Tags: trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger

i want to add in my trigger before delete to compare if the owner of a form is the user , if it true then i can delete but in the object form i don't have an object that refer to the user , how can i do it please ?

My code:

```
trigger FormBeforeDelete on CORE_Form__c (before delete) {

Id currentUser = UserInfo.getUserId();

for (CORE_Form__c form : trigger.old )
{
     // if(Trigger.isBefore){}

    if(form.CreatedById != currentUser && form.CORE_Status__c  == 'Validated')
    {
        form.addError('Cannot delete form - you are not the owner & the status as Validated');
    } 
    
     if(form.CreatedById != currentUser && form.CORE_Status__c  == 'Finished')
    {
        form.addError('Cannot delete form - you are not the owner');
    } 
    
     if(form.CreatedById != currentUser && form.CORE_Status__c  == 'In Progress')
    {
        form.addError('Cannot delete form - you are not the owner');
    } 



}
}
```

Comment: you can [edit] your question if you have existing code or more specifics to give.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the context user is the owner easily using `UserInfo.getUserId()` and `OwnerId` which exists on all objects, for example:

```java
Id currentUser = UserInfo.getUserId();

for(Account a : Trigger.new) {
    if(currentUser != a.OwnerId) {
        throw new InvalidUserException(); // or your logic
    }
}
```

Ideally you can avoid writing any custom trigger logic through permissions or even a validation rule.

Comment: Thank you , can you please check the code that i just posted

Comment: I don't see any code? Did you try to edit it into your question?

Comment: I see your code now but not sure what you want me to check. I would recommend not using `CreatedById` and `OwnerId` instead as the owner is able to be changed but the creator is not. That can lead to issues where the creator is deactivated.

Comment: To echo @nbrown, this looks like an issue that could be solved with clicks, not code. You may be able to use a Flow (I'm not sure if you can) to do this, or you could use object permissions. If you're using Lightning Experience, I wonder about also (not only doing this) showing the delete button only if the running user is the owner. Not sure if that's possible, but would be interesting.